# How to print text as watermark on images vertically in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I Here is my Code

```
# Json file in which Easyocr anotations have saved.
img = cv2.imread('dummy.jpg')
img1 = img.copy()
#rotoated because anotation have according to vertical alignment of image i have matched the orientation
img1=cv2.rotate(img1,rotateCode=cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
rects = []
with open('dummy.json') as jsn:
    jsn_dict = json.load(jsn)
for k in jsn_dict['textAnnotations']:
    vertices= k['boundingPoly']['vertices']
    cv2.rectangle(img1,list(vertices[2].values()),list(vertices[0].values()),[0,255,0],10)
# I want to put predicted text on top of bounding boxes vertically because my image is rotated anti clockwise
    cv2.putText(img1, k['description'], list(vertices[0].values()),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,5,[0,255,0],5)
```

I have the code mentioned above I am labelling the recognized text. First step is, I put the image into the OCR model and it returns some values according to the image, in which we have three values for every detected text. These values are the vertex of the bounding box, the text that was recognized, and the accuracy percentage. But my problem is that my image was rotated by the `Exif` orientation value but cv2 read it as a zero angle and my text is printing horizontally. I want to print text on an image vertically. I have tried so many times but could not resolve my problem. I hope I have explained it well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
import cv2


def transparentOverlay(src, overlay, pos=(0, 0), scale=1):
"""
:param src: Input Color Background Image
:param overlay: transparent Image (BGRA)
:param pos:  position where the image to be blit.
:param scale : scale factor of transparent image.
:return: Resultant Image
"""
overlay = cv2.resize(overlay, (0, 0), fx=scale, fy=scale)
h, w, _ = overlay.shape  # Size of foreground
rows, cols, _ = src.shape  # Size of background Image
y, x = pos[0], pos[1]  # Position of foreground/overlay image

# loop over all pixels and apply the blending equation
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        if x + i >= rows or y + j >= cols:
            continue
        alpha = float(overlay[i][j][3] / 255.0)  # read the alpha channel
        src[x + i][y + j] = alpha * overlay[i][j][:3] + (1 - alpha) * src[x + i][y + j]
return src


def addImageWatermark(LogoImage,MainImage,opacity,pos=(10,100),):
opacity = opacity / 100

OriImg = cv2.imread(MainImage, -1)
waterImg = cv2.imread(LogoImage, -1)

tempImg = OriImg.copy()
print(tempImg.shape)

overlay = transparentOverlay(tempImg, waterImg, pos)
output = OriImg.copy()
# apply the overlay
cv2.addWeighted(overlay, opacity, output, 1 - opacity, 0, output)

cv2.imshow('Life2Coding', output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
addImageWatermark('./logo.png','./hanif.jpg',100,(10,100))
```

Comment: Bro your solution is good but want to print text not the image

Answer (score 0):

Rotate your image 90º clockwise, add the text, and rotate the image back to the original.

```
# Rotate 90º clockwise
img_rot = cv2.rotate(img1 , cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
# Add your text here, adjusting x and y coordinates to the new orientation.
#   The new adjusted coordinates will be:
#   (x2, y2) = (original_height - y, x)
# [...]
# Rotate back
img1 = cv2.rotate(img_rot, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
```

Comment: I am adding text by using given coordinates and that coordinates will change when I rotate image

Comment: Yes. That is why the original piece of code said `adjusting x and y coordinates to the new orientation`. Anyway I edited the answer with how the coordinates should change for 90º clockwise rotation.